# ApiTestCase class request function returning "function name must be a string" error

Tags: php, rest, unit-testing, phpunit, slim

I'm currently doing integration testing for my small personal project on Slim - testing with PHPunit. I set up my own test class extending the [ApiTestCase](https://github.com/lzakrzewski/slim-integration-testing-example/blob/master/tests/ApiTestCase.php) class.

I only tried it with simple code and PHPStorm is not indicating any errors. I'm on PHP 7.

```
class SQLTest extends ApiTestCase
{
    public function test_if_successful(){
        $this->request('POST', '/v1/users/login', ['email' => 'm@yahoo.com', 'password' => '123']);
        $this->assertThatResponseHasStatus(200);
    }
}
```

When run on PHPunit, it gave me an error saying the function name must be a string on the line where I call the request() function.

Here is the request() function in the ApiTestCase class.

```
protected function request($method, $url, array $requestParameters = [])
    {
        $request = $this->prepareRequest($method, $url, $requestParameters);
        $response = new Response();

        $app = $this->app;
        $this->response = $app($request, $response);
    }
```

The error pointed is at the last line:

```
$this->response = $app($request, $response);
```

Comment: @odan I tried your suggestion for the original problem I had but I think you deleted it? Thanks though, I got it to work but now PHPUnit is giving me a 404 Not Found error (I got 200 OK on Postman). I read through the link you gave and they're basically identical. Is it possible that PHPUnit can't find the url? (thus, the 404 not found error?)

Comment: I deleted my answer, because I think it was not the correct solution for you. The [linked](https://github.com/lzakrzewski/slim-integration-testing-example/blob/master/tests/BlogTest.php#L10) Github repository shows you how to use it correctly. There are already good and working examples. PHPUnit has nothing to do with it. Without further details (code) I can't help.

Comment: @odan ah but it did help my original problem though... okay thanks for the link btw, I'll examine it further